# Need advice for INI parsing and validation

Tags: parsing, python-3.x, configparser, configobj

My constraints

- A mandatory section
- An optional section
- A single-level section
- Only one identical option by section
- Text values that can look like this:
  Electric= yes6batteries
  Electric= yes4battery
  Electric= yes8solar_panel
  Electric= yes
  Thermal= no
- Conditional options, for example:
  Electric should not exist (or should be no) if Thermal= yes but must be if Thermal= no
- Need to get the number or the content of the error/conflict lines

I looked ConfigObj but I soon abandoned because not validated for Python3.
I started working with ConfigParser but I'm not sure to reach what I want.
So I ask you what you would do in my place or if there is a library best suited to my need.

Answer (score 0):

[TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml) isn't exactly the INI format, but it looks almost like it.
There's a [python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/toml) for TOML, and it works with Python 3.